# $.getJSON() datos duplicados

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

hola gente paso a comentarles mi problema, en el desarrollo de un visor web observo que al hacer una petision con el meto de JQuery $.getJSON() por momentos me trae datos duplicados o simplemente se ve que se ejecuta mas de 1 vez como se observa en la imagen adjunta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es posible evitar esto? ya que los objetos que crea permanecen en el mapa y no los puedo eliminar, algo así como que esta perdiendo la referencia al primer objeto y solo se puede interactuar con el ultimo creado(es decir eliminar y agregar ese mismo y no el anterior).
desde ya agradezco su respuesta!!

NOTA: adjunto también el código donde llamo el método por si llegan a notar algo que este haciendo mal.

```js
function traerDatos(o) {
 $("#Espera_JSON").modal({backdrop: "static"});
 $.getJSON(o.getURL())
  .always(function() {
   $("#Espera_JSON").modal("hide");
  })
  .done(function( data ) {
   o.setGeoJson(data);
     })
     .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
      $("#Espera_JSON").modal("hide");
      $("#Error_JSON").modal("show");
  });
}



var ArrayOBJ = [new Generales(),provincias,establecimientos,new DRH(), new SEMA(),new DFA(),new Mineria(),new DMA];

$("ul.menu li a").click(function(event) {

 $(".form-check-input").on( 'change', function() {

     if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {

       for (o in ArrayOBJ) {
        if(event.target.id == ArrayOBJ[o].nombre){
         recorrerLi(ArrayOBJ[o],$(this).val(),1);
        }
       }    

     } else {

   for (o in ArrayOBJ) {
    if(event.target.id == ArrayOBJ[o].nombre){
     recorrerLi(ArrayOBJ[o],$(this).val(),0);
    }
   }
     }
 });
});

function recorrerLi(obj,id,b) {
 id=id.replace(/ /g,"_");//reemplazo espacios por '_'
 if (b==1) {
     for (var propiedad in obj){
       if( propiedad === id ){
         (obj[propiedad].geoJson=="")?traerDatos(obj[propiedad]):obj[propiedad].agregarCapa();
                
       }
     }
 }else{
     for (var propiedad in obj){
       if( propiedad === id ){
        obj[propiedad].quitarCapa();

       }
     }
 }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Veo que tienes la llamada a `traerDatos` dentro de un bucle `for`, así que es normal que se realice varias veces

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta @PabloLozano , si lo hice dentro del bucle porque para cada elemento del DOM necesitaba saber cual fue accionado, una vez encontrado un objeto ligado a este ejecuta su propia URL en el ajax...no logro ver porque se ejecutaría varias veces si el objeto una vez seteado no entrara por la función de TraerDatos

Comment: Prueba a poner la condición así: `(obj[propiedad].geoJson)?traerDatos(obj[propiedad]):obj[propiedad].agregarCapa();`

Comment: Gracias, en cuanto pueda lo comprobare y avisare si es que me sirvió

Answer (score 0):

viendo tu función ajax, creo que te faltan algunos parámetros, uno de los parámetros que puedes usar es   "async: false", básicamente ajax en método asíncrono es decir que no espera una respuesta, por esta razón puede se que se ejecute mas de una vez en distintos momentos.

de esta forma se declara en tu llamada ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: myUrl,
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    //resultado
    //...
  }
});
```

Esto coincidiría actualmente usando $ .getJSON () de esta manera:

```
$.getJSON(myUrl, myData, function(data) { 
  // parametros
});
```

cualquier cosa estoy para ayudar

saludos

Comment: async: false ya depende del navegador y esa forma no funciona

Comment: No es recomendable hacer llamadas síncronas nunca, es una opción que el propio navegador, si la usas, te avisa de que no deberías hacerlo

Comment: muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta @PatricioFernandez , aunque esta vez no me conviene detener la petision ajax necesito que sea 'async'